# How to define value and id for enum in protobuf? (proto java client)

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

I am new to protobuf usage.

i am planning to write protobuf def with enum(s) in it.

is there any way to provide id, value and as well description in it.

after compilation i want generated enum should be equivalent as below example

```
enum Sample{
  W(0, "W"), P(0, "P"), C(0, "C"), B(0, "B")
  private final int id;
  private final String value;

  private Status(int id, String value) {
    this.id= id;
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to generate exactly the Java enum in your example, but you can use "custom options" to add arbitrary annotation to protobuf declarations. See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#options) (scroll down a little bit to "custom options").

```
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

extend google.protobuf.EnumValueOptions {
  optional string name = 51234;
}

enum MyEnum {
  FOO = 0 [(name) = "foo"];
  BAR = 1 [(name) = "bar"];
}
```

The annotation is accessed through the `EnumValueDescriptor` interface.

Comment: This is for proto2 syntax only. How to make the same for proto3 ?